# Count the number of lines in a Java String

Tags: java, string, lines

Need some compact code for counting the number of lines in a string in Java. The string is to be separated by `\r` or `\n`. Each instance of those newline characters will be considered as a separate line. For example -

```
"Hello\nWorld\nThis\nIs\t"
```

should return 4. The prototype is

```
private static int countLines(String str) {...}
```

Can someone provide a compact set of statements? I have a solution at here but it is too long, I think. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if the string ends with a newline? Would you count that as another line? So, would "foo\nbar\n" be two lines or three?

Comment: Another way with JDK/11 is to make use of the [`String.lines()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631407/1746118) API.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
private static int countLines(String str){
   String[] lines = str.split("\r\n|\r|\n");
   return  lines.length;
}
```

Comment: While this is perfectly good for almost all use-cases, I just want to point out that this creates a lot of Strings, that are never beeing used - but still requires memory and gc-ing. It probably only a problem on a heavily used server, or a phone or something, but it is still something of a cludge.

Comment: Its not valid answer. It doesn't work if your String contains only new lines.

Comment: @kukis If you want to include trailing newlines you have to pass an explicit argument of -1 for the limit parameter of split (ie str.split("\r\n|\r|\n", -1); if you look at the docs here:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29 it has more information.

Comment: Also worth noting. If you use StringUtils from apache commons, their version of 'split' does NOT include trailing newlines. Even if you pass a negative value for length, trailing newlines will still be stripped.

Comment: a one liner `int count = text.split("\r\n|\r|\n").length;`

Comment: since java 1.1 there is a LineNumberReader. see my answer below.

Answer (score 29):

How about this:

```
String yourInput = "...";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\r\n|\r|\n").matcher(yourInput);
int lines = 1;
while (m.find())
{
    lines ++;
}
```

This way you don't need to split the String into a lot of new String objects, which will be cleaned up by the garbage collector later. (This happens when using `String.split(String);`).

Comment: Should lines be initialized to 0 here or 1?

Comment: To 1, since the first newline character that will be found after line 1.

Comment: The correct regex should be (\r\n)|(\n)|(\r) otherwise this code returns 3 instead of 2 for "First\r\nSecond"  because it matches \r and \n before matching \r\n.

Comment: thank you !!!!! I was looking for this in a very long time, and finally i found. Worked just perfectly.

Comment: optimalisation suggestion: precompile the pattern once : private static final Pattern EOL_PATTERN=Pattern.compile("..."); outside the method. And use it in the method: Matcher m =EOL_PATTERN.matcher(yourinput);

Answer (score 27):

With Java-11 and above you can do the same using the **[`String.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lines())** API as follows :

```
String sample = "Hello\nWorld\nThis\nIs\t";
System.out.println(sample.lines().count()); // returns 4
```

The API doc states the following as a portion of it for the description:-

> ```
> Returns:
> the stream of lines extracted from this string
> ```

Answer (score 22):

A very simple solution, which does not create String objects, arrays or other (complex) objects, is to use the following:

```
public static int countLines(String str) {
    if(str == null || str.isEmpty())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int lines = 1;
    int pos = 0;
    while ((pos = str.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1) != 0) {
        lines++;
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Note, that if you use other EOL terminators you need to modify this example a little.

Comment: use '\n’ instead of "\n" and ++lines instead of lines++

Answer (score 13):

I am using:

```
public static int countLines(String input) throws IOException {
    LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new StringReader(input));
    lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    return lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
}
```

`LineNumberReader` is in the `java.io` package: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html

Answer (score 11):

If you have the lines from the file already in a string, you could do this:

```
int len = txt.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")).length;
```

**EDIT:**

Just in case you ever need to read the contents from a file (I know you said you didn't, but this is for future reference), I recommend using [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) to read the file contents into a string. It's a great library and has many other useful methods. Here's a simple example:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

int getNumLinesInFile(File file) {

    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
    return content.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")).length;
}
```

Comment: The line is not from a file, it is just a string. But it is a nice code though

Comment: Shouldn't the FileUtils.readFileToString(file) parameter be a java.io.File instance, your code above is passing a String (I'm using Commons-io 2.4)?

Comment: @BigRich - Yes, you are right. Thank you for pointing it out, I corrected the code.

Comment: This code won't work if you get a file created on Windows and your JVM is on a linux os, and the other way around won't work as well. If you can assume that files are in the format of the os you're running your jvm on, that's ok.

Comment: @autra - That's more of a general type of problem. You should fix the line endings to be applicable for the given OS before you try to parse the file. Or, if you know the file is in a Windows format (e.g. you know the line ending type), you could code for that as well. I don't really think that's a reason to downvote my answer though, but you're entitled to your opinion.

Answer (score 10):

If you use Java 8 then:

```
long lines = stringWithNewlines.chars().filter(x -> x == '\n').count() + 1;
```

(+1 in the end is to count last line if string is trimmed)

One line solution

Comment: nice, but what do you do for `\r` only?

Comment: On Android this will requires API 24 - thats not gonna work for most people

Answer (score 3):

This is a quicker version:

```
public static int countLines(String str)
{
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return 0;
    int lines = 1;
    int len = str.length();
    for( int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++) {
        char c = str.charAt(pos);
        if( c == '\r' ) {
            lines++;
            if ( pos+1 < len && str.charAt(pos+1) == '\n' )
                pos++;
        } else if( c == '\n' ) {
            lines++;
        }
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
public int countLineEndings(String str){

    str = str.replace("\r\n", "\n"); // convert windows line endings to linux format 
    str = str.replace("\r", "\n"); // convert (remaining) mac line endings to linux format

    return str.length() - str.replace("\n", "").length(); // count total line endings
}
```

number of lines = countLineEndings(str) + 1

Greetings :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//import java.util.regex.Matcher;
//import java.util.regex.Pattern;

private static Pattern newlinePattern = Pattern.compile("\r\n|\r|\n");

public static int lineCount(String input) {
    Matcher m = newlinePattern.matcher(input);
    int count = 0;
    int matcherEnd = -1;
    while (m.find()) {
        matcherEnd = m.end();
        count++;
    }
    if (matcherEnd < input.length()) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

This will count the last line if it doesn't end in cr/lf cr lf

Answer (score 0):

```
"Hello\nWorld\nthis\nIs\t".split("[\n\r]").length
```

You could also do

```
"Hello\nWorld\nthis\nis".split(System.getProperty("line.separator")).length
```

to use the systems default line separator character(s).

Comment: if it should work correctly with files then it would be `System.getProperty ("line.separator");`. But I thing it's not the case and your previous (before edit) solution was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a solution using no "magic" regexes, or other complex sdk features.

Obviously, the regex matcher is probably better to use in real life, as its quicker to write. (And it is probably bug free too...)

On the other hand, You should be able to understand whats going on here...

If you want to handle the case \r\n as a single new-line (msdos-convention) you have to add your own code.  Hint, you need another variable that keeps track of the previous character matched...

```
int lines= 1;

for( int pos = 0; pos < yourInput.length(); pos++){
    char c = yourInput.charAt(pos);
    if( c == "\r" || c== "\n" ) {
        lines++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if lines are separated by "\r\n" as it is on windows platform? your method will double the line count

Comment: As this probably is homework, I just mentioned that case in the answer. You will find it above...

Answer (score 0):

```
new StringTokenizer(str, "\r\n").countTokens();
```

Note that this will not count empty lines (\n\n).

CRLF (\r\n) counts as single line break.

Answer (score 0):

This method will allocate an array of chars, it should be used instead of iterating over string.length() as length() uses number of Unicode characters rather than chars.

```
int countChars(String str, char chr) {
    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    for(char cur : charArray)
        if(cur==chr) count++;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: your method does not allocate any memory, maybe toCharArray() will allocate it, but this is implementation-specific, in some JDKs it just returns the utf-16 representation of the string as char array

Answer (score -1):

What about `StringUtils.countMatches()`.

In your case

```
StringUtils.countMatches("Hello\nWorld\nThis\nIs\t", "\n") + StringUtils.countMatches("Hello\nWorld\nThis\nIs\t", "\r") + 1
```

should work fine.

Comment: This is ridiculous, just use the `lines` method on a `String`.

Comment: Yes, that is a good solution since Java 11. Will not work in Java 8.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you look for something like this

```
String s; 
s.split("\n\r");
```

Look for the instructions here for [Java's String Split method](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

If you have any problem, post your code

Comment: This doesn't work since it only splits on the sequence of `\n\r`.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work. It should be a regrex there. I recommend it as a suggestion rather than a real implementation:)