# Count Words from a string containing \n

Tags: java

I have below mentioned string

```
String str = "\nArticle\n\nArticle\nArticle";
```

I want total number of count. How can i get this?
As the string contain \n so always it gives 1 instead of 3

Comment: How do you do it in the first place? How can we correct the code you've produced without seeing it.

Comment: Count of words separated by \n?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850203/count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-java-string and [2]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string

Comment: Reviewer here: can you expand your question a little? You'll get more positive feedback to your question if you include what you've tried so far, what you've researched/Googled and what errors/problems you're encountering with your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, I will show you a simple example:

```
String str = "\nArticle\n\nArticle\nArticle";

// Split the String by \n
String[] words = str.split("\n");

// Keep the count of words
int wordCount = 0;

for(String word : words){
   // Only count non-empty Strings
   if(!word.isEmpty()) {
       wordCount++;
   }
}

// Check, answer is 3
System.out.println(wordCount);
```