# java getting Last line(fastest way) from a String Variable

Tags: java, android, string, java-me

I have a String Variable Contains lines of text

```
line1(Contains String)
line2(Contains String)
line3(Contains String)
line4(Contains String)
```

My requitement is to get a Last line of text?

Could any one help?

Comment: Read about StringReader: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096621/how-to-read-a-string-line-per-line

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
paragraph.substring(paragraph.lastIndexOf("\n"));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
// get the index of last new line character
int startIndex = str.lastIndexOf("\n");

String result = null;

// see if its valid index then just substring it to the end from that

if(startIndex!=-1 && startIndex!= str.length()){
  str.subString(startIndex+1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

let say your string is like this

```
String s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaa \n bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \n cccccccccccccccccc \nddddddddddddddddddd";
```

Now you can split it using

```
    String[] arr = s.split("\n");
    if (arr != null) {
        // get last line using : arr[arr.length - 1]
        System.out.println("Last    =====     " + arr[arr.length - 1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
paragraph.substring(paragraph.lastIndexOf("\n"));
```

Comment: variable naming was a coincidence? :-)

Comment: @rajesh cheers :) and that is exisiting line in my code too :)

Answer (score 1):

String[] lines = fileContents.split("\n");
String lastLine = lines[lines.length - 1];

this lastline variable would contain last line.

Answer (score 0):

Example (slow solution)

```
String line = null;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myString);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  line = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

After this line is your last line.